# Failed with error: Could not read from remote repository || git

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea, git-push

I am using Intelliji Idea. When I try to push my project to github repository I getting this message for 2 times:[image]

And then I get this message:

[image]

What I need to do to push my project?

Comment: Have you pressed `Yes` button?

Comment: @SajibKhan Yes, when I try to press `Yes` button this message appears again

Comment: Did you add your current `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into your github account & also can you check if the remote url is ok: `git remote -v`?

Comment: When I write `git remote -v` in Git Bash in path of my project I get this message: `origin  git@github.com:yalef/TBotPasta.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:yalef/TBotPasta.git (push)`

Comment: And I didnt have a ssh key. I have added it. Then I try to push againg. I get this message in Intelliji Idea: `Authentication using key C:\Users\Vlad/.ssh/id_rsa failed.`

Comment: Have you added your ssh-key into your GitHub account? https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Comment: @SajibKhan yes this is help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such issues usually occur when there is no SSH-key configured, or IDE could not find it. AS a test, check push from command line to make sure SSH access is configured correctly. Make sure you have the ssh key and it is added to GitHub. See https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

The error is rather generic, unfortunately. There are request to show more details and improve error reporting - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-72176 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168179

At the moment, when some git operation fails, you could always check a more detailed output of the git command using the Console tab of the Version Control toolwindow.